# How can I make this more efficient? Python DNA Generator

Tags: python, performance, ram, memory-efficient

I have a code that generates DNA and then replicates the dna strand however many times, then it cuts each line at a random point. I need to be able to generate 20k lines at least but this takes 30 minutes to do. I was wondering if there was a way to make this code more efficient? Thanks

```
import sys
import numpy as NP
import fileinput
import re
import random

#Generate Random DNA Sequence

def random_dna_sequence(length):
    return ''.join(random.choice('ACTG') for each in range(length))
#DNA sequences with equal base probability

def base_frequency(dna):
    D = {}
    for base in 'ATCG':
        D[base] = dna.count(base)/float(len(dna))
    return D

for each in range(1):
    dna = random_dna_sequence(300)
    f= open("GeneratedDNA.txt", "w+")
    print(dna, file=f)
    f.close()
    f= open("OrigionalStrand.txt", "w+")
    print(dna, file=f)
    f.close()

Value =int(input("Enter How Many Replica Strands You Want to Generate: "))
for x in range(Value):
    with open("GeneratedDNA.txt") as f_in, open("GeneratedDNA.txt", "a") as f_out :
        for row in f_in.readlines()[-1:] :
            f_out.write(row)
            f_out.close()

min_no_space = 55 #minimum length without spaces
max_no_space = 75 # max sequence length without space
no_space = 0
with open("GeneratedDNA.txt","r") as f, 
open("GeneratedShortReads.txt","w") as w: 
    for line in f:
        for c in line:
            w.write(c)
            if no_space > min_no_space:
                if random.randint(1,9) == 1 or no_space >= max_no_space:
                    w.write("\n")
                    no_space = 0
            else:
                no_space += 1
    f.close()
    w.close()
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? You generate a random DNA sequence 300 bases long and generate short reads from it. But it's not really clear what you want your short reads to look like. Can you explain your algorithm for creating `GeneratedShortReads.txt`?

Comment: @TBurgis Thanks for your reply. My aim was to make short reads between the lengths of 55-75 Base pairs but have them chop each line at random points to make it random. Please let me know if that is clear.

Answer (score 0):

1. Do not open or close a file in a loop, instead load file data in a variable at the beginning of the code and write the output in an other variable and write it to the file at the end of the code.
2. Getting random data is often expensive. You could load like 1000 random numbers once and then use them as random numbers generator.
3. Use PyPy as interpreter, it is up 6 times quicker than CPython : https://pypy.org/
4. If it is not enough, use a quicker language than Python. I suggest Golang or C++ : https://dev.to/albertdugba/go-or-python-and-why-58ob

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to generate short reads (e.g. Illumina or similar) from a sequence of DNA try this, it is much quicker than your code

```
import numpy as np
def random_dna_sequence(length):
    return ''.join(random.choice('ACTG') for each in range(length))
```

We'll start with a random DNA sequence that is 500,000 bp long. From that we'll make 20,000 short reads that have a mean length of 60bp with a standard deviation of 10 bp:

```
seq_len = 500000
mean_read_length = 60
read_length_sd = 10
num_reads = 20000

my_dna = random_dna_sequence(seq_len)

# Generate random read lengths
read_lengths = [int(x) for x in np.random.normal(mean_read_length,read_length_sd,num_reads)]

# Generate random offsets
offsets = np.random.randint(0,seq_len,num_reads)

# Make the reads
reads = [my_dna[offset:offset+length] for offset,length in zip(offsets,read_lengths)]

# Add code to write reads to file ...
```

Comment: I wasn't sure what you wanted your short reads to look like so used numpy's function that generates random numbers from a normal distribution - you need to supply the mean of the distribution (in this case 60) and a standard deviation (in this case I chose 10). To generate reads between 55 and 75 instead you could do `read_lengths = np.random.randint(55,76,num_reads)`